# I can't find source and design tab in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-kepler, windowbuilder

I feels like this is a silly question. But I installed windowbuilder correctly. And update eclipse. And I made a new java class and opened it with windowbulder editor. But I can't find the source and design tab. Given below is my eclipse window. I'm very new to eclipe please help me for this.[image]

Comment: May we assume that you've read [the WindowBuilder FAQ](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ffaq.html)?

Answer (score 1):

This problem may arise when your class will be opened with normal java editor.
Just follow the below mentioned step to make source and design button appear:

1. Right click on class file
2. Select open With
3. Select open with windows builder